# How can I fit this table in landscape orientation?

Tags: tables, line-breaking

```
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{ccllcc}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Amount(INR Cr)}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Round}} & \textbf{Stage} & \textbf{Investors} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Pre Money Valuation (INR Cr)}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Post Money Valuation (INR Cr)}} \\
    \hline
    417   & 8     & Growth-PE & IIFL VC, Sequoia Capital India &       & 30496 \\
    1001.82 & 7     & Late  & Wellington Management, Faering Capital, TVS Capital, Others & 25971.15 & 26972.97 \\
    1492.2 & 6     & Growth-PE & IIFL VC, Faering Capital, TVS Capital, Sequoia Capital India, Others &       & 26078.5 \\
    135   & 5     & Growth-PE & A91 Partners, Faering Capital, TVS Capital & 14049.7 & 14184.7 \\
    654.58 & 4     & Growth-PE & A91 Partners, Faering Capital, TVS Capital, Others & 5471.74 & 6126.32 \\
    165   & 3     & Growth-PE & Fairfax Holdings &       &  \\
    315   & 2     & Growth-PE & Fairfax Holdings &       &  \\
    384.44 & 1     & Growth-PE & Fairfax Holdings &       &  \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
\end{landscape}
```

Comment: Any news? You got two answers, does they solve your problem? If yes, you can upvote them and accept the best of them (as I see, so far you not accept no answer to your questions, why?).

Answer (score 2):

I would *not* try to typeset this table in landscape mode, since doing so would be treating the symptoms rather than the cause of the table's underlying problem. The problem is that you're not allowing line breaks in columns 4, 5, and 6.

To fix this problem, I suggest you switch from a `tabular` to a `tabularx` environment and allow line breaking in all cells of column 4 and in headers of columns 5 and 6. I would also (a) align the numbers in columns 1, 5, and 6 on their explicit or implicit decimal markers and (b) move the unit legend (INR Cr) to separate lines.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,siunitx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}  % flush-left, not justified
\newcommand\mC[1]{\multicolumn{1}{L}{#1}}
\sisetup{group-four-digits=true} % show thousands separator for 4-digits numbers

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\setlength\tabcolsep{3.5pt}    % default: 6pt
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a less-cramped look

\caption{Add caption}
\label{tab:addlabel}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} 
    S[table-format=4.2] c l L *{2}{S[table-format=5.2]} @{}}
    \hline
    {\bfseries Amount} & 
    \bfseries Round & 
    \bfseries Stage & 
    \bfseries Investors & 
    \mC{\bfseries Pre Money Valuation} & 
    \mC{\bfseries Post Money Valuation} \\
    {(INR Cr)} & & & & {(INR Cr)} & {(INR Cr)} \\ % units on separate line
    \hline
    417     & 8 & Growth-PE & IIFL VC, Sequoia Capital India &       & 30496 \\
    1001.82 & 7 & Late      & Wellington Management, Faering Capital, TVS Capital, Others          & 25971.15 & 26972.97 \\
    1492.2  & 6 & Growth-PE & IIFL VC, Faering Capital, TVS Capital, Sequoia Capital India, Others &          & 26078.5  \\
    135     & 5 & Growth-PE & A91 Partners, Faering Capital, TVS Capital         & 14049.7 & 14184.7 \\
    654.58  & 4 & Growth-PE & A91 Partners, Faering Capital, TVS Capital, Others & 5471.74 & 6126.32 \\
    165     & 3 & Growth-PE & Fairfax Holdings &       &  \\
    315     & 2 & Growth-PE & Fairfax Holdings &       &  \\
    384.44  & 1 & Growth-PE & Fairfax Holdings &       &  \\
    \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: this is exactly what I wanted in my mind ...Thanks!!

Comment: I have another table which that I've tried to replicate the above code for. But it isn't exactly working

Comment: @Jimi13ABC - Sadly, but probably not surprisingly, my mind-reading skills are utterly worthless. Unless you post the code for the second table,  the odds that I -- or anyone else, for that matter -- will be able to help you meaningfully are decidedly poor. Please post a *new* query, with the code of the second table you wish to fix. Thanks.

Comment: Hey, thanks for solving the second query! This saved me a bunch of time. But I'm rather new to working with Latex. Any recommendations for learning material on how I can effectively learn how to deal with importing various types of tables ?

Comment: @Jimi - Please see [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11/5001)

Answer (score 2):

Similar to @Mico answer (+1) but with `tabularray` package. For table rules is employed `booktabs` package and for page layout `geometry` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx} % load corresponding packages

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\caption{Add caption}
\label{tab:addlabel}
\sisetup{group-four-digits=true,
         
\begin{tblr}{colsep=4pt,
             colspec={@{} S[table-format=4.2] c l 
                          X[2.2, l]
                     *{2}{X[c, si={table-format=5.2}]} @{}},
            row{1} = {font=\small\bfseries},
            row{1,2} = {guard}
            }
    \toprule
Amount  & Round & Stage & Investors & Pre Money Valuation   & Post Money Valuation  \\
(INR Cr) &      &       &           & (INR Cr)              & (INR Cr)              \\ 
    \midrule
417     & 8     & Growth-PE & IIFL VC, Sequoia Capital India
                                    &                       & 30496                 \\
1001.82 & 7     & Late      & Wellington Management, Faering Capital, TVS Capital, Others
                                    & 25971.15              & 26972.97              \\
1492.2  & 6     & Growth-PE & IIFL VC, Faering Capital, TVS Capital, Sequoia Capital India, Others
                                    &                       & 26078.5               \\
135     & 5     & Growth-PE & A91 Partners, Faering Capital, TVS Capital         
                                    & 14049.7               & 14184.7               \\
654.58  & 4     & Growth-PE & A91 Partners, Faering Capital, TVS Capital, Others 
                                    & 5471.74               & 6126.32               \\
165     & 3     & Growth-PE & Fairfax Holdings              
                                    &                       &                       \\
315     & 2     & Growth-PE & Fairfax Holdings 
                                    &                       &                       \\
384.44  & 1     & Growth-PE & Fairfax Holdings      
                                    &                       &                       \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]